# [Swig]Convert C++ char* to java byte[]

Tags: java, c++, swig

In C++ I have this struct

```
typedef struct
{
    char* sensorDataBuffer;
    int sensorDataBufferSize;

} SALDetections;
```

And it has been automatic convert the char* to String, like this:

```
public void setSensorDataBuffer(String value) {
    SALJNI.SALDetections_sensorDataBuffer_set(swigCPtr, this, value);
  }

  public String getSensorDataBuffer() {
    return SALJNI.SALDetections_sensorDataBuffer_get(swigCPtr, this);
  }
```

How should I write the interface script to convert char* to byte[]?

I tried these code, which I found online, but it's not working.

```
%typemap(jni) char *sensorDataBuffer "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype) char *sensorDataBuffer "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) char *sensorDataBuffer "byte[]"
%typemap(javaout) char *sensorDataBuffer {
    return $jnicall;
}
```

Comment: Do you want this to be taking a copy of the byte array you pass in, or keeping hold of the underlying array?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any advice?